# DynamoDB import_table Error:'DynamoDB' object has no attribute 'import_table'

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have walked through the steps of importing a S3 csv to a new dynamodb table in the AWS console successfully. But, when trying to with boto3 I'm getting the error `'DynamoDB' object has no attribute 'import_table'`. Typically you would just need to set the table but since the `import_table` creates a new table I'm not sure what is needed.

I use the `self.db_client` to delete the old table prior to importing as this import will happen on a reoccurring schedule but that shouldn't affect anything to my knowledge.

```
self.db_client = self.session.client("dynamodb")

def create_table_from_csv(self) -> dict:
        """Function to import csv from s3 to dynamodb
        Args:
            none
        Returns:

        """
        try:
            self.logger.info(
                "Import report from S3 to new dynamodb table: {}".format(
                    self.table_name
                )
            )
            response = self.db_client.import_table(
                S3BucketSource={
                    "S3Bucket": self.bucket_name,
                    "S3KeyPrefix": self.report_csv_key,
                },
                InputFormat="CSV",
                TableCreationParameters={
                    "TableName": self.table_name,
                    "AttributeDefinitions": [
                        {"AttributeName": "instanceArn", "AttributeType": "S"},
                        {"AttributeName": "instanceName", "AttributeType": "S"},
                    ],
                    "KeySchema": [
                        {"AttributeName": "instanceArn", "KeyType": "HASH"},
                        {"AttributeName": "instanceName", "KeyType": "Range"},
                    ],
                    "BillingMode": "PROVISIONED",
                    "ProvisionedThroughput": {
                        "ReadCapacityUnits": 5,
                        "WriteCapacityUnits": 5,
                    },
                    "SSESpecification": {
                        "Enabled": True,
                        "SSEType": "KMS",
                        "KMSMasterKeyId": self.table_key_arn,
                    },
                },
            )
        except ClientError as error:
            self.logger.error(
                "Error: failed to upload report({}) from s3 to new dynamodb table".format(
                    self.report_csv_key
                )
            )
            self.logger.error("Error message:" + str(error))

        return response
```

Comment: Print `boto3.__version__` to check. Or do you have unseen code that reassigns `self.db_client`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't state which version of boto3 you are using. Import table functionality is approx 1 year old,so you should ensure you are using one of the latest boto3 packages.

You must be on at least version 1.24.55

https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.rst#12455

```
import boto3

self.db_client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
```

Comment: I'm using boto3 version 1.28.85

Comment: Try import your client using the example I shared.

Comment: Found that AWSLambdaPowertoolsPython layer was overriding my boto3 version to a older version than I had listed. Overriding this fixed it